# How can I draw circle on a map?

Tags: python

Here is my dataframe:

```
Boston
Zipcode Employees   Latitude    Longitude
0   02021   174 -71.131057  42.228065
1   02026   193 -71.143038  42.237719
3   02109   45  -71.054027  42.363498
4   02110   14  -71.053642  42.357649
5   02111   30  -71.060280  42.350586
6   02113   77  -71.054618  42.365215
8   02115   116 -71.095106  42.343330
10  02118   318 -71.072103  42.339342
11  02119   804 -71.085268  42.323002
12  02120   168 -71.097569  42.332539
13  02121   781 -71.086649  42.305792
15  02124   1938    -71.066702  42.281721
16  02125   859 -71.053049  42.310813
17  02126   882 -71.090424  42.272444
19  02128   786 -71.016037  42.375254
21  02130   886 -71.114080  42.309087
22  02131   1222    -71.121464  42.285216
23  02132   1348    -71.168150  42.280316
24  02134   230 -71.123323  42.355355
25  02135   584 -71.147046  42.357537
26  02136   1712    -71.125550  42.255064
28  02152   119 -70.960324  42.351129
29  02163   1   -71.120420  42.367263
30  02186   361 -71.113223  42.258883
31  02199   4   -71.082279  42.346991
32  02210   35  -71.044281  42.347148
33  02215   83  -71.103877  42.348709
34  02459   27  -71.187563  42.286356
35  02467   66  -71.157691  42.314277
```

And I want to draw circles on my map, each circle corresponds to one point, the size of the circle depends on the number of Employees
Here are my map code (I try to use marker, but I think circle is better:

```
boston_map=folium.Map([Boston['Longitude'].mean(), Boston['Latitude'].mean()],zoom_start=12)
incidents2=plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(boston_map)
for Latitude,Longitude,Employees in zip(Boston.Latitude,Boston.Longitude,Boston.Employees):
    folium.Marker(location=[Latitude,Longitude],icon=None,popup=Employees).add_to(incidents2)
boston_map.add_child(incidents2)
boston_map
```

Here is my map:
[image]

If the number of employees can show in the circle, it will be better! Thank you very much!

Comment: what have you found with Google ? In few seconds I found on Google: [CircleMarker](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.CircleMarker) and 7th example on [quickstart](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html)

Comment: BTW: first you use `Longitude, Latitude` in `Map()` but later you use in different order `Latitude, Longitude` in `Marker()`. Probably you have wrong column's names in data. [Boston](https://www.latlong.net/place/boston-ma-usa-18552.html) has lat: `42.361145`, long: `-71.057083.` but you have values `42` in column `Longitude`

Answer (score 2):

To draw circles you can use [CircleMarker](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.CircleMarker) instead of `Marker`

---

**BTW:** you have wrong column's names. [Boston](https://www.latlong.net/place/boston-ma-usa-18552.html) has `lat: 42.361145, long: -71.057083`  but you have values `42` in column `Longitude` and values `-71` in column `Latitude`

---

Because I don't use Juputer so I save map in HTML file and use `webbrowser` to automatically open it in web browser.

Because it created big circles so I divide `Employees` to create smaller circles. But now some circles are very small and it shows number of circles instead circles. Maybe it should be used `math.log()` or other method to make it smaller (normalized).

I use `tooltip=str(employees)` to display number when you hover circle.

```
text = '''
Zipcode Employees       Longitude Latitude
0   02021   174 -71.131057  42.228065
1   02026   193 -71.143038  42.237719
3   02109   45  -71.054027  42.363498
4   02110   14  -71.053642  42.357649
5   02111   30  -71.060280  42.350586
6   02113   77  -71.054618  42.365215
8   02115   116 -71.095106  42.343330
10  02118   318 -71.072103  42.339342
11  02119   804 -71.085268  42.323002
12  02120   168 -71.097569  42.332539
13  02121   781 -71.086649  42.305792
15  02124   1938    -71.066702  42.281721
16  02125   859 -71.053049  42.310813
17  02126   882 -71.090424  42.272444
19  02128   786 -71.016037  42.375254
21  02130   886 -71.114080  42.309087
22  02131   1222    -71.121464  42.285216
23  02132   1348    -71.168150  42.280316
24  02134   230 -71.123323  42.355355
25  02135   584 -71.147046  42.357537
26  02136   1712    -71.125550  42.255064
28  02152   119 -70.960324  42.351129
29  02163   1   -71.120420  42.367263
30  02186   361 -71.113223  42.258883
31  02199   4   -71.082279  42.346991
32  02210   35  -71.044281  42.347148
33  02215   83  -71.103877  42.348709
34  02459   27  -71.187563  42.286356
35  02467   66  -71.157691  42.314277
'''
import pandas as pd
import io
import folium
import folium.plugins

boston = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

boston_map = folium.Map([boston.Latitude.mean(), boston.Longitude.mean(), ], zoom_start=12)

incidents2 = folium.plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(boston_map)

for latitude, longitude, employees in zip(boston.Latitude, boston.Longitude, boston.Employees):
    print(latitude, longitude, employees)
    folium.vector_layers.CircleMarker(
        location=[latitude, longitude],
        tooltip=str(employees),
        radius=employees/10,
        color='#3186cc',
        fill=True,
        fill_color='#3186cc'        
    ).add_to(incidents2)
    
boston_map.add_child(incidents2)

# display in web browser
import webbrowser
boston_map.save('map.html')
webbrowser.open('map.html')
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:** answer for question [how to add a label on each circle in a folium.circile map python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039161/how-to-add-a-label-on-each-circle-in-a-folium-circile-map-python) shows how to use `Marker` with `icon=DivIcon(text)` to add text but it doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: I added `tooltip=str(employees),` to display nubmer when you hover circle.